# How to make all particles rotate to face the camera (Blender 3.4)

Tags: particles

I realise this question has been asked before, but the answers don't seem to apply to the new version of Blender.

I have textured planes should face the camera no matter how wind or other influences interfere with them during the particle simulation. If they rotate, the illusion is destroyed.

I tried adding Track To/Damped Tracks constraints to the particle source object.
But it didn't seem to transfer over to the particle system.
Could not enable Rotation either to solve the issue.
Ideas?